# An Intricate Sigma Question how to solve?

Tags: calculus

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)}{(3^k)}
\end{align*}$$

I used the root test for this problem and distributed $\frac {(k+1)}{{(3^k)}^{(1/k)}}$ this got me $\frac{(k+1)}{(3)}$ so I plug in $k =0$ and I got $\frac 1 3$ convergent. Is this the correct way of doing the root test?

Comment: No, you need to raise the entire summand to the power $1/k$ to get $(\frac{k+1}{3^k})^{1/k}$=$\frac{(k+1)^{1/k}}{3}$. Then why did you plug in 0 for $k$? The root test says to find the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$, which will be challenging in this case. I'd recommend the ratio test instead, if you know that!

Comment: I do plug in k+1 for k then divide by the original.

Comment: Yes, then you take the limit of your result as $k$ goes to infinity. This limit should be much easier to find than the one you get with the root test.

Comment: Somehow I still got 1/3 yet my book says 3/4. This is perplexing indeed.

Comment: You should be getting 1/3. What does the "3/4" in your book refer to?

Comment: convergence 3/4 as k goes to infinity. I am trying to figure out how they came to this number?

Comment: possibly they accidentally calculated this sum: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k}{3^k}=\frac{3}{4}$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}=-\frac{d}{dx}\left (\frac{x}{x-1}\right )=-\frac{d}{dx}\left (\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{x^k}\right )=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k}{x^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k}{x^k}$$
we have (with $x=3$)
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k+1}{3^k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{k}{3^k}+\frac{1}{3^k} \right )=\frac{3}{(3-1)^2}+\frac{3}{3-1}=\frac{9}{4}$$